# Encountering error "runtime error 91" with "Do Until"

Tags: excel

I'm kinda new to this whole thing and the site and recently encountered an error with my code that I am unable to solve. My objective is to get my macro to be able to cut any cells containing the phrase "Subcontractor : " from column A to column L's cell which is offset (1,11).
My code allows it to do so but even though I get my desired results, however provides an error 91.

Code:

```
Sub SiteAccess()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook 'Define your workbooks and worksheets as variables
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("SiteAccessReports")

Dim cc As Excel.Range, ee As Long

Do
For Each cc In Range("A1:A30000") 'Or whatever yours is
If cc.Value Like "*SUBCONTRACTOR : *" Then
cc.Cut Destination:=cc.Offset(1, 11)
For ee = mySheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row Step -1
If Cells(ee, 1) = 0 _
Then Cells(ee, 1).EntireRow.Delete

     Next ee
Exit For
End If
Next
Loop Until cc.Value = "***END OF REPORT*** " 'Error Line

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: cc.Value is being cleared before the loop hits the END OF REPORT line. cc.Value is also empty to start and so hits an immediate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want but you will need to refine the initial range selection to make sure you're not picking up any Empty values.

```
Sub SiteAccess()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook 'Define your     workbooks and worksheets as variables
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("SiteAccessReports")

Dim cc As Range

For Each cc In Range("A5:A14") 'Or whatever yours is

    If cc.Value Like "*SUBCONTRACTOR : *" Then

        cc.Cut Destination:=cc.Offset(1, 11)
        Cells(cc.Row - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

    If cc.Value Like "***END OF REPORT***" Then Exit Sub

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Could I get some help with the last part of the coding as well? As you placed "Then Exit Sub" at the bottom, I dont really understand how I would go about adding additional line of commands after this within the same sub

Comment: That line just drops you out of the sub if the for each hits the "END OF REPORT line. If you take it out, it should drop out of the for each loop and carry on.